# Using Struct or Enum in classifying Condiments for Fast Food Console Application

Tags: c#

I've been learning C# for about three months. I am heading toward ASP.NET MVC, but I'm in the phase right now where I'm coding each day just building things as much as possible to reinforce these fundamentals, while I work toward a larger goal. That's my brief .NET experience overview.

The application will allow users to select from a menu of predefined foods and place an order and have their food served, of course. I have designed classes defining a Product which implements a Food interface which defines what food must have and there is another interface for what beverages must have. There are classes for products which are then grouped into more specific instances of Burgers, Fries, Salads etc., I think you see the point. Data access is just POCO .. so anyway when using methods for serving up the food the user must be able to specify whether or not they want condiments or not and then the program will make decisions on what to do next based on that decision. Should I use a struct or enum:

```
public enum Condiments 
        {
        Mayonaise,
        Mustard,
        Ketchup,
        Secret Sauce,


        }
```

Really just confused on how to put the condiments as options without creating properties or additional classes. So I could have simplified this by just saying asking ... "How would you do that?"

Answer (score 1):

> just confused on how to put the condiments as options without creating properties or additional classes

I would create a class for that and other lookups. Hard coding them means that in future if you need to add a new item, you will have to re-build and re deploy. To avoid that, i would prefer creating a lookup table in the database and a POCO class. Then load them in cache and bind them to appropriate source.

If you still want to hard code them, you can do the binding like this

```
Yourobject.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Condiments));
```

Comment: "Hard coding them means that in future if you need to add a new item, you will have to re-build and re deploy." Amen. Enums (and especially flag-style enums) should only be used for program-oriented things, not user-oriented things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enum.GetNames(typeof(Condiments))` to get an array of the condiment names and present that list to the user.

Comment: And is this how you display the contents of the array? Or does this just get the data and now you have to do something else to show it to the user in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use an Enum, with the Flags attribute. This would allow you to combine multiple selections into one value. In the example below Mustard & SecretSauce are chosen by "ORing" the two values together. Even when multiple selections are made, you can use the HasFlag() method to check if a particular selection was made.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Choose Mustard & SecretSauce
        Condiments selected = Condiments.Mustard | Condiments.SecretSauce;

        Console.WriteLine(selected);


        // Is SecretSauce selected
        bool has = selected.HasFlag(Condiments.SecretSauce);

        Console.WriteLine(has);

    }
}

[Flags]
public enum Condiments
{
    Mayonaise = 0x01,
    Mustard = 0x02,
    Ketchup = 0x04,
    SecretSauce = 0x08,
}
```

For more info on the FlasAttribute check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx